# show panel when button is pressed

Tags: button, primefaces, panel

I have a button and a panel in primefaces. I want the panel to be visible when I press the button. How can I do it with primefaces?

I have the code

```
        <p:commandButton value="Search" ajax="false"
        actionListener="#{myBean.searchPatients}" onclick="panelwv.show();">
    </p:commandButton>
    <p:panel widgetvar="panelwv" visible="false" closable="true" toggleable="true" >
```

but it does not work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a typo in your code, the attribute you need is `widgetVar`:

```
<p:commandButton value="Search" ajax="false"
    actionListener="#{myBean.searchPatients}" onclick="panelwv.show();">
</p:commandButton>
<p:panel widgetVar="panelwv" visible="false" closable="true" toggleable="true"/>
```

If you don't want to render your panel at all you should consider using the `rendered` attribute of the component.

Comment: If I want to display the panel when the searchPatients method finishes, what should I change??

Comment: In that case you need to wait until the search completes, then open the panel. `oncomplete="panelwv.show();"`. You should also change `ajax="true"`, I'm not sure how this supposed to work whith `ajax="false"`.

Comment: with ajax="true" the elements in panel are not computed from my bean, while with ajax="false" the panel does not appear at all

Comment: since the question discussed in these comments is not anymore about "show panel when button is pressed", I suggest you to post a new question and leave this question with the correct answer.

Comment: anyway, the fact that your panel elements aren't computed in your bean could mean that you aren't computing those values in your bean. If you think that this is not the case then post a new question with your concrete problem. Also see my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dialog for this . You can also examine this

https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/dialog/basic.xhtml

```
<p:commandButton value="Search" ajax="false"
actionListener="#{myBean.searchPatients}" oncomplete="PF('dlg1').show();">
</p:commandButton>
<p:dialog header="Basic Dialog" widgetVar="dlg1" minHeight="40">
<p:panel  visible="false" closable="true" toggleable="true"/>
</p:dialog>
```